# Don't show query results if they appear in the other query

Tags: sql

In my application each manager has a work pattern (for example Monday-Friday). But I also have a table "pattern_changes" where they can insert data if they cannot be present at work.

With the first query I can show who is available today, according to the pattern assigned to them:

```
SELECT distinct gu.first_name || ' ' || gu.last_name
FROM patterns pa JOIN fmanager_pattern fp
ON pa.id = fp.pattern_id
JOIN fmanagers fm 
ON fm.id = fp.fmanager_id
JOIN gen_users gu
ON gu.user_id = fm.user_id
WHERE (TO_CHAR(pa.start_dt, 'DY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') LIKE TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'DY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') AND pa.start_dt < sysdate and pa.end_dt > sysdate) 
OR (TO_CHAR(pa.end_dt, 'DY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') LIKE TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'DY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') AND pa.start_dt < sysdate and pa.end_dt > sysdate)
OR TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'D') BETWEEN TO_CHAR(pa.start_dt, 'D') AND TO_CHAR(pa.end_dt, 'D') AND pa.start_dt < sysdate and pa.end_dt > sysdate
OR TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'D')+7 BETWEEN TO_CHAR(pa.start_dt, 'D') AND TO_CHAR(pa.start_dt, 'D')+7 AND pa.start_dt < sysdate and pa.end_dt > sysdate
```

In the second query I can show who is not available today, according to the pattern_changes table.

```
SELECT fm.id, gu.first_name || ' ' || gu.last_name
FROM fmanagers fm JOIN pattern_changes pc 
ON pc.fmanagers_id = fm.id
JOIN gen_users gu 
ON gu.user_id = fm.user_id
WHERE pc.change_dt < sysdate and pc.end_dt > sysdate
OR pc.change_dt = to_char(sysdate)
OR pc.end_dt = to_char(sysdate))
```

For example, the first query returns: ADAM and EVA 
The second query returns ADAM

So I just want to see EVA as a result.

I tried to do it with NOT IN or NOT EXISTS but neither of them work.
Can anybody help?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Make it easy to help you, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve!

Comment: This can help you: https://teamsql.io/blog/?p=923